# An inequality connected to measure given on a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

There is a measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-algebra given. I am to proof that:
$\mu(\underline{\lim}A_n) \le\ \lim \mu(A_n) \le \overline{\lim} \mu(A_n)$. 
I don't know how to start this proof. The second inequality seems to be obvious, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu(\liminf_{n}E_{n})=\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k\geq n}E_{k}\right)=\lim_{n}\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{k\geq n}E_{k}\right)=\liminf_{n}\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{k\geq n}E_{k}\right)\leq\liminf_{n}\mu(E_{n})$.